# How to consume the wcf services in ios development

Tags: ios, wcf, web-services, ipad

I'm working on an iPad application which needs to consume a WCF service, what are the known solutions for creating bindings in Objective-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to consume wcf service in your cocoa touch application you could use this link

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/39819-how-to-call-wcf-service.html

also
try changing the configuration. I found a walkthrough at at the code project: How to create a JSON WCF RESTful Service in 60 seconds on proper setup.

Comment: Please delete this Answer as it waste Developers valuable time.